# Is this powdery mildew? Plant is potted and was unwatered for a long period

Tags: mildew, sweet-pea

A potted everlasting sweet pea in my garden nearly died due to lack of water earlier this year. I managed to revive it but its older leaves are yellowing and have what looks like powdery mildew coating many of them. The upper leaves are largely clear and the plant seems to have begun growing well again. Can anyone confirm that this is in fact powdery mildew? I can rub off parts of the white coating with my thumb which I read may suggest it's not powdery mildew.

If it is indeed powdery mildew then is milk and water the best way to treat it? Should I just remove the leaves that are worst affected?

[image: mid-level leaves]

Comment: It looks like two different fungal diseases. The leaves on the bottom of the picture don't look as much like powdery mildew, but the leaf above the center of the picture with the very light white spots does. Neem oil is excellent for powdery mildew. Milk and water can be risky, because one cause of powdery mildew is excess water on the foliage.